# Using eclipse, can I create android app that will test an already installed app?

Tags: android, eclipse

Apologies if this question is already answered - I searched but couldn't find anything quite like it - it seems all assume the app I'm trying to test I've also developed. I'm also new to android automated testing.
I'm trying to automate the testing of an app, but I don't develop the app - so I don't have the source code to the app.  I just get an apk file to install and then test.  What I would like to do is use Eclipse to develop a test (possibly using fonemonkey) to run and test the app.  The app is already installed on the emulator avd, so don't want install it.  Is this possible?  If so, how do I set up the project to run the emulator and launch the app so that I can begin testing it?

Comment: Normally you would need the source code to run unit tests on an android application.

Comment: That's a bummer.  I'm not the developer - I'm the QA person.  I only get the apk.  I'm just looking for a way to automate the testing - I've used selenium for our web tests, but it doesn't test native apps on the android, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you can use [robotium](http://code.google.com/p/robotium/).

Comment: Doesn't robotium require the source code as well?  I've just discovered that fonemonkey does, so that won't work.  I'm the QA person so I don't have access to the source code.

Comment: Hmm, I just checked again. It looks like you either need the source code OR the jar file containing the classes. Can you at least get a hold of the JAR files?

Comment: You are correct - I misunderstood the meaning of the section titled "Test Android APK File With Robotium" on http://code.google.com/p/robotium/wiki/RobotiumTutorials. Thanks!

Comment: If this solved your issue, mark the answer as correct in case others may encounter this same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your app could launch other application using an Intent. Beyond that, I am not sure how you would automate the testing of the GUI.